# What pattern I have to use to correctly call Child methodes?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, jackson

I need help with how to correctly use java. Currently I rely on Jackson Object mapper and want to replace it with some pattern probably.

I have an abstract class:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class AbstractClass {
  private String first;
  private Object second;
}
```

also an extened class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class ExtendedClass extends AbstractClass {
  @Getter
  public static final String FIRST_TYPE= "EXTENDED";

  private String first;
  private Second second;

  @Getter
  public static class Second {
    private String value;
  }
}
```

Later I do such a lame thing probably which I need to fix, cause I don't think it's Java way to use object mapper instead of some clever pattern here:

```
  @SneakyThrows
  private SomeProps mapProps(String value) {
    try {
      Values values = objectMapper.readValue(value, Values.class);
      AbstractClass valueProp = values.getProp();
      var valuesType = valueProp.getFirst();
      String ExtendedClassStaticFirstValue FieldValue =
        (String) getTypeFromStatic(Extended.class);
      // TODO: want to implement more checking here 
      if (ExtendedClassStaticValue 
        .equals(valuesType)) {
        // TODO: @pdemyane: please, think about!
        Extended valueProp =
          objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(valueProp), Extended.class);
        return map(valueProp);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      log.error("Json processing exception in processing source from", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

How to write code so that not to rely on Object mapper? Do I understand correctly that this is completle wrong?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Do you want to get rid of Jackson at all? Do you want to remove your Jackson dependency on your data classes? Java SE does not provide any json related libraries, so you rely on an json implementation anyway.

Comment: @asbachb at least to get rid of second assignment, where I conver abstract model to json, if possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance) is what you are looking for.